# Custom CalendarView

Tags: android

Хочу написать банальное приложение в котором будет календарь с событиями, чтобы при первом нажатии на дату выбиралась дата  и закрашивалась цветом до следующей выбранной даты либо на следующие 7 дней.

Я создал календарь:

```
calendarView = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Попытался сделать через:

```
calendarView.setDate(1484784000000L);
```

больше одной даты увы задать нельзя и при нажатии на другую дату предыдущая дата сбивается.

Следующая попытка была сделать через:

```
calendarView.setMinDate(1484870400000L);
calendarView.setMaxDate(1485302400000L);
```

но снова, не позволяет сделать несколько вариантов выбора, только один, то есть вот такой вариант не работает:

```
calendarView.setMinDate(1484870400000L);
calendarView.setMaxDate(1485302400000L);

calendarView.setMinDate(1485475200000L);
calendarView.setMaxDate(1485648000000L);
```

Может стоит использовать сторонние библиотеки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы зашли не с той стороны. `Calendar` -- это не элемент пользовательского интерфейса `View`. Это Java-класс, используемый для работы с датами (подробнее [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)), позволяющий, например, задавать отдельные компоненты для одной даты (год, день, час и т.д.)

Для отображения календаря на экране следует использовать `CalendarView` (документация [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)). Однако, боюсь, он Вам мало чем поможет, поскольку используется для выбора даты.

Если Вы хотите написать свой многофункциональный календарь, Вам придётся создавать его с нуля из других `View` или модифицировать существующий.